# Conditional Formatting a column based on specific condition on other column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

Given:I have table shown below

```
| A | Total | % A |
|---|-------|-----|
| 2 | 5     | 40% |
| 4 | 19    | 22% |
| 3 | 10    | 30% |
| 1 | 8     | 13% |
| 1 | 3     | 34% |
```

And I want to conditional format column `% A`:

Highest Percentage as **Green** and 
Lowest Percentage as **Red**

But condition is column `Total` must be greater than or equal to 4 (i.e. >=4) to be considered as particular row to be used for conditional formatting.

*For an Example:*

In above table I want to perform conditional formatting for only those row in `% A` whose `Total` column is (i.e. >=4)

Considering table something like this

```
| A | Total | % A |
|---|-------|-----|
| 2 | 5     | 40% |
| 4 | 19    | 22% |
| 3 | 10    | 30% |
| 1 | 8     | 13% |
```

And Now I want to do conditional formatting.

I tried filtering but this formatting those cell also whose `Table` column is less than < 4.

Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: Please be specific all about the criteria,, what i got is,, Highest value as Green and Lowest as Red,, could you elaborate ,,`But condition is column Total must be greater than or equal to 4 (i.e. >=4) to be considered as particular row to be used for conditional formatting.`?

Comment: Hey @RajeshS I want to look for only those row whose `Total` is (>=4) and then I want to perform conditional formating on those cell on column `% A`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- Formula for Highest Value:

[image]

---

- Formula for Lowest Value:

[image]

---

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I tried: Conditional formatting > New rules (From Drop down) > Use a formula to determine which cells to format. Type the formula but still not working

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar,, I've used the sample data provoded by you,, and uploaded the Screen Shot along with the formula I've used,, Y still is not working difficult to rule out,, better [Edit] your post and upload link of the file to workout or load on any cloud !!